# Could someone please help explain to me what '收尸' means?

Tags: translation, meaning, vocabulary, meaning-in-context, phrase

Could someone please help explain to me what '收尸' means?

I'm learning what this '收尸' words mean, I've looked in ichiba, ichacha and mdbg and I still couldn't understand.

They all said that the meaning is 'bury the dead', but when I saw some of the sentences they showed as examples, some of them showed '收尸' as 'corpse'.

Is '收尸' considered as one 'word'? Or is it: '收'=verb '尸'=object?

Also, one of the example I completely didn't understand is:
- '她是法络德.翁海尔的养女, ***为他的收尸人跑腿***. '
- The adopted daughter of Pharod Wormhair, she runs errands for his Collectors.
I assumed it's supposed to be 'she is Fa Luo De, Wang Hai Er's adopted daughter, ....' I can't understand the '收尸人' in the continuation of that sentence.

Comment: Collector=collector of dead bodies (translation also in jukuu), for context search "Pharod Wormhair" online, Planescape: Torment https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%BC%82%E5%9F%9F%E9%95%87%E9%AD%82%E6%9B%B2 
    法络德 Pharod

    专门发死人财的收尸人。他住在法印城下的被掩没的村庄，并且发现了清除者所使用的墓地。他不仅重复贩卖尸体给万亡会(清除者)，顺便连死者的财物也通通拿走。最后死于无名氏所制造的众多怨灵之手，转生到巴托异界的人头骨柱中。

Answer (score 1):

Like dan said, 收尸 is a verb, which means 'collecting (a) dead body'.

The example in question only makes sense if you knew who Pharod Wormhair is. Basically he is someone who makes money from dead bodies, and he has his collectors, who collect dead bodies for him. Here is [an introduction of him](http://torment.wikia.com/wiki/Pharod) if you want to know more.
Here 收尸人 is used to describe his collectors. The translation from 'collectors' to 收尸人 is only specific to this context, otherwise 'collector' doesn't directly translate to this.

Normally, the word 收尸 is used between people who are relatives/very close.
For example, we have A, whose only acquaintance in the world is B. Then B dies. Now we say, A has no one to collect their body.

Ask if you're still unsure about this word.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand, 收尸 literally means collecting dead body

however, usually it is extended to means **"to clear up the mess for somebody"**

examples:

- "你做错了事，我替你收尸"——you've done something wrong, and I clear up the mess
  for you

Answer (score 0):

'收尸' 收 is a verb meaning "collect". 尸 means ‘corpse’, 'dead body'. 收尸人 means the one who collects the corpse of someone else. if you can put a 的 in the middle:收尸的人, you might have a better understanding I guess.

Comment: So '为他的收尸人跑腿' means 'running an errand for him as a dead body collector'?

Comment: I am not sure who is 他 in the context, but suppose to be someone who is dead. my understand is (法络德.翁海尔的)养女 running an errand for the guy who is the dead body collector, not for Him -- the guy who is dead. hope this clear.

Comment: Pharod Wormhair (Fa Luo De, Wang Hai Er)  ＂is a notorious collector boss in Sigil＂ see http://torment.wikia.com/wiki/Pharod （so it seems adopted daughter merely runs errands for them w/o being one herself)

Answer (score 0):

It always means that someone dead and otherone to help to collect his body.